# RabbitMQ generates lot of queues, which are live forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

I will be very appreciate for some help with resolving my issue.

I'm using Rabbitmq and there are a lot of generated queues(with names like amq.gen-pMJVWygd3iLb_buXp1oUyw), which are durable and leave forever.

The problem that such queues has exchange core.timeout, but there are also queue which should handle core.timeout.

So I'm stuck in this moment and can't find where this queues are generates.

Comment: Could you post some of your code? How are you creating your queues?

Comment: To be truly, I'm not familiar with RabbitMQ to much and this code was wrote before me.
So this is example how we are define queue - 
`queue = MQ.queue(Logging::LOGGING_QUEUE, :durable => true)`

But there is also a method
            @@queues[name] = bunny.queue()

Comment: Ok, but to be able to help you I need to see some of the code in the queue creation. What I think is happening is that you are letting Rabbit in your code to create durable queues automatically when connecting to an exchange or something similar. Obviously, these queues persist. But I can't be sure if I don't see the code.

Comment: There it is. You are creating durable queues. Check inside the class MQ in that method queue and try putting a name on the queue, if what you want is to create the same queue again, all depends of what you want to do exactly.

Comment: @Ron Thank you for your help. There is such code for exhange method in our Queuable module:           `@@exchanges[name] = bunny.exchange(name, exchange_definition(name).exchange_config)`
 `queue(name).bind(name) if exchange_definition(name).bind_on_queue`

And in exchange_config there is such params: `{:type => @type, :durable => @durable}`. May this durable option be true for auto generated queues? Thanks a lot

Comment: `durable => true` is for the queue to persist, to not disappear when you shut down your server. That is what's causing that your queue is not deleted. The "auto-generation" is actually that you are not giving any name to the queue, and rabbit is assigning one. You should check the docs before going into it (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-ruby.html). They have good examples there.

Comment: @Ron yes, but all queues which I expected to be has names and they should be durable. The problem is that there are normal core.timeout queue and hundreds of auto generated queues with exchange core.timeout. And I can't find there they are generating in the system. I think that your first answer is pretty near to what happening, but I'm still can't find this place. Thanks.

Comment: @Ron thank you, I will try to investigate it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your clarifications, the problem seems to be that you are letting Rabbit in your code to create durable queues automatically when connecting to an exchange.

Try debugging your class MQ to see where your queue creation is being trigger in the exchange `core.timeout`.

Check on [the docs](http://rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-ruby.html) for more info about Rabbit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But the problem is that this issue occurs only in production. It is ok on localhost for some reason. So it is little bit hard to debug it.

Comment: You can debug the client locally, connecting to the rabbitmq production server, if that helps...